# Understanding fork() in for loop

Tags: c, unix, loops, for-loop, fork

I have a problem with understanding `fork()`. Can anybody explain me, what will this program print? Because I preparing for the exam and it is the typical question. Exactly in this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    for(i = fork(); i < fork(); i++)
        execlp(“echo”, “sono”, argv[0], 0);
    system(“echo i+$i”);
}
```

For me, what is not understandable is this line

```
for(i = fork(); i < fork(); i++)
```

What does it mean? Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: If this is typical, you have a twisted instructor.

Comment: fork returns two things: `0` to the new child process, and the pid of the child to the original "parent" process. this code is basically a massive fork bomb

Comment: i think that it is not possible to predict output because `fork()` returns the `pid` of the child to `i` .

Comment: @anon its the child pid in the parent process, but its zero (`0`) for the child process, which makes this... interesting (still twisted, though =P)

Comment: `system(“echo i+$i”)` doesn't make sense to me, unless it is just meant to generate `i+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crunching the first *full* iteration from initialization through *all* processes finishing the first loop context, the following will happen:

**1. Initializer**

`i` is initialized from  `i = fork();`

- Process **parent**: `i = pid(child1)`
- Child process **child1**: `i = 0`

Hitting the conditional test in each process something interesting happens

**2. Process : parent**

`i < fork()` will fork another child process, **child2**. If the returned `pid(child2)` is greater than `pid(child1)`, the conditional test is met and the parent process continues to the loop body

**3. Process : child1**

- `i` is zero from the initializer
- `i < fork()` will fork a child process, **child3**. If the returned `pid(child3)` is greater than the value of `i` (which is zero, so it always will be), the conditional test is met and the child1 process continues to the loop body

**4. Process: child2**

- Inherits `i` from parent, where `i` is `pid(child1)`
- This process was spawned from evaluating `i < fork()`, so `fork()` will eval as 0. Therefore...
- `i < fork()` will evaluate to be `child1(pid) < 0`, which will never be true. The conditional test fails, and the for-loop is terminated.

**5. Process: child3**

- Inherits `i = 0` from its parent, child1.
- This process was spawned from evaluating `i < fork()`, so `fork()` will eval as 0. Therefore...
- `i < fork()` will evaluate to be `0 < 0`, which will never be true. The conditional test fails and the for-loop is terminated.

At this point, parent and child1 are the only two processes that make it to the loop body. The other two (child2 and child3) both failed their conditional checks. As a result, the following things happen:

**6. The Final Steps**

- parent process is **replaced** with `execlp("echo", "sono", argv[0], 0);`
- child1 process is **replaced** with `execlp("echo", "sono", argv[0], 0);`
- child2 process invokes `system("echo i+$i");` and **terminates**.
- child3 process invokes `system("echo i+$i");` and **terminates**.

**This is important:** At no time do *any* of the aforementioned processes evaluate the for-conditional more than once. Anything that succeeds the conditional test will be replaced with an `execlp()` process launch. Anything that fails the conditional test will leave the loop and terminate after the `system()` call. Therefore, once any process makes it past the conditional (either by success or failure) it will never `fork()` another process.

In other words, **This is NOT a `fork()` bomb.** If either the loop body or the suffix code past the loop forked another instance of *this* process, it would easily be a `fork()` bomb, but *neither* do so.

---

Note: it is *possible* that a pid-rollover, where process ids reset and start "filling in the holes", causes the first initial fork to introduce a child2 pid that is *less* than the  child1 pid. If that happens, (however unlikely) the results would only change to this:

- **parent process invokes `system(“echo i+$i”);` and terminates.**
- child1 process is replaced with `execlp("echo", "sono", argv[0], 0);`
- child2 process invokes `system("echo i+$i");` and terminates.
- child3 process invokes `system("echo i+$i");` and terminates.

Not bloody likely, but then neither is winning a lottery, and people think it will happen to them all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the yours exhaustive answer!

Comment: @Sergeys_K No problem. Just glad it made sense.

Comment: As i can understand - it will be a correct graph http://files.devit.by/graph.jpg. It was a perfect for me, now I become undestand better! Thank you once again!

Answer (score 3):

that code is incredibly twisted and wrong. 
But when you don't know what a code does, just run it "manually"

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    for(i = fork(); i < fork(); i++)
        execlp(“echo”, “sono”, argv[0], 0);
    system(“echo i+$i”);
}
```

### parent process:

```
i = fork();
```

here `i` contains the PID of the newly created process

```
execlp(“echo”, “sono”, argv[0], 0);
```

as @Whozcraig corrected me in the comment (and shame on me for making that 1st year mistake)

it runs echo and outputs `"sono a.out"` on the output (considering the name of prog is `a.out`). [`execlp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) replaces the current process with its arguments and stops execution here.

*before edit I was saying it was `fork()`ing indefinitely*

### child process:

```
i = fork();
```

here `i` contains the value 0, indicating this is the newly created process.

```
execlp(“echo”, “sono”, argv[0], 0);
```

is out again… replacing current process with its arguments and stops execution once echo is over.

*before edit, I was saying it was `fork()`ing again.

So **at first look** it looks like you got a twisted and crazy fork bomb, that will grow exponentially. But in the end, you got a twisted and crazy single fork that only executes the `execlp()` content twice.

N.B.: `system(“echo i+$i”);` is nonsense, as `$i` has no meaning in the context of this code. Even though it will never be executed.

in the end your instructor is *really* perverse.

Comment: Your analysis of this as a fork bomb may change considerably if you recall that [`execlp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) *replaces* the current running process.